# Google sheets add-on -- Deceptive post-message URIs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to publish a google add-on and am currently trying to get OAuth verification from the google admin team. They came back to me and said that I have the following post-message origin URL which does not belong to my top level domain:

- post_message_origins: https://gsuite.google.com

I'm not sure what this is referring to in my code -- does anyone know what it might mean?

Thanks in advance,

Anant

Comment: Is your Google account a GSuite account?

Comment: My google account is part of the company gsuite account -- how would that affect the running of the addon?

Comment: The GSuite account has an Administrator.  To find out who your Administrator is, check the following link:[https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960)  The Administrator can allow or prevent users taking certain actions.  I'm not saying that this is your problem, but I'd want to rule out the possibility that that the Administrator can help you out.